# Improper alphabetic constant

Tags: errors

I'm using two counters (*linefrom* and *lineto*) to specify the range of lines to be printed in my listing:

```
  \setcounter{linefrom}{1}
  \setcounter{lineto}{5}
```

The following passes compilation and works as expected:

```
\lstinputlisting[linerange={1-\value{lineto}}]{
  ...
}
```

Whilst the following generates an error:

```
\lstinputlisting[linerange={\value{linefrom}-\value{lineto}}]{
  ...
}
```

The error being:

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \value
```

Could someone enlighten me, please? A Minimal Working Example is available at: https://gist.github.com/3187943

```
\documentclass [11pt,oneside,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{hello.c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  // return 0;
}
\end{filecontents*}

\lstset{
  numbers=left,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  aboveskip=0pt,
  belowskip=0pt,
  showlines = true
}

\lstdefinestyle{highlight}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{orange}
}

\newcounter{linefrom}
\newcounter{lineto}

\makeatletter
\def\code{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}
\def\@with[#1]#2{
  \setcounter{linefrom}{1}
  \foreach \x in {#1}{
    \setcounter{lineto}{\x}
    \addtocounter{lineto}{-1}
    \lstinputlisting[linerange={1-\thelineto}]{
      #2
    }
    \addtocounter{linefrom}{\x}
    \addtocounter{linefrom}{-1}
    \addtocounter{lineto}{1}
    \lstinputlisting[linerange={4-\thelineto},style=highlight,firstnumber=last]{
      #2
    }
    \addtocounter{linefrom}{1}
  }
  \lstinputlisting[firstline=\the\value{linefrom},firstnumber=last]{
    #2
  }
}
\def\@without#1{
  \lstinputlisting[]{
    #1
  }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\code[4]{hello.c}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not without a real example.

Comment: Just added a MWE. Lines 25 and 31 contain hard-coded values. Changing them to `\thelinefrom` provokes the error.

Comment: I've combined your files and they don't give any errors. Can try to replicate the error on what I have included above?

Comment: As I just said, to reproduce the error simply replace the hardcoded values in lines 25 and 31 (my.sty) to \thelinefrom. I've created a new revision with this change for you: https://gist.github.com/3187943/dfcb43488ac8dd81e465586636871b0e9388b85d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `linerange` wants to see an explicit number as the start. So we present it one:

```
\def\@with[#1]#2{
  \setcounter{linefrom}{1}
  \foreach \x in {#1}{
    \setcounter{lineto}{\x}
    \addtocounter{lineto}{-1}
    \lstinputlisting[linerange={1-\thelineto}]{
      #2
    }
    \addtocounter{linefrom}{\x}
    \addtocounter{linefrom}{-1}
    \addtocounter{lineto}{1}
    \begingroup\edef\y{\endgroup
      \noexpand\lstinputlisting[linerange=\thelinefrom-\thelineto,style=highlight,firstnumber=last]}%
     \y{#2}
    \addtocounter{linefrom}{1}
  }
  \lstinputlisting[firstline=\thelinefrom,firstnumber=last]{#2}
}
```

The `\edef` will expand completely `\thelinefrom` and `\thelineto`.

Comment: This did the trick. I've updated the gist with a working version, in case it is needed by someone else.

Answer (score 11):

I can tell you what the error means at least. an alphabetic constant uses the backtic to get the character code of a letter:

```
$ tex
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012)
**\relax

*\count0=`a

*\showthe\count0
> 97.
```

The error you show is what you get if you put a command after the backtick that does not expand to a character token:

```
*\count0=`\hfill  
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \hfill
```

---

As no MWE is supplied I haven't tried to reproduce but you might to better with `\thelinefrom`  and `\thelineto` rather than use `\value` as they will expand to character tokens of the digits in the value.

---

I copied the files that you linked and ran them without error in texlive 2012 producing:

[image]

Comment: Just added a MWE.

Comment: just a supplement: Chinese characters in lstlisting could also raise the same error.  while it is said that lstlisting does not support UTF8-characters.